# changing element id with jQuery not work for my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

want to assign 2 functions to a button when using the click event of jQuery, it will work like this: I have a div that is hidden behind another div when click the button that slides up div with jQuery to animate ... this #show ID shows the div, and the ID #hide hides the div, how can I assign 2 different IDs for the same button? I have done this using the ID attribute and attr ... is changed to #hide, but the function linked to this ID is not performedry

http://jsfiddle.net/dca2b/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="hiddendiv"> 
    <a href="#" id="show">show</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    height: 400px;
}
.footer {
    display: inline-table;
    background: #ff8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.hiddendiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #252525;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.hiddendiv a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 20px 0px #333;
}
.hiddendiv a:hover {
    color: #f0f;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#show").click(function () {
    $(".hiddendiv").animate({
        top: "-=250"
    }, "slow");
    $("#show").attr("id", "hide");
});

$("#hide").click(function () {
    $(".hiddendiv").animate({
        top: "+=250"
    }, "slow");
    $("#hide").attr("id", "show");
});
```

Comment: You can't assign two IDs to an HTML element. You can, however, assign multiple classes.

Comment: tried again with classes and it seems that the button is only with first class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of parts to my answer, bear with me:

(1) The reason it isn't working right now is because when you run `$("#hide").click(function() { ...`, there aren't yet any elements on the page with the `hide` id, so the function doesn't get set to run anywhere. One method you can use to get around this is to do the following:

```
$(".hiddendiv").on('click', '#hide', function() {
   ...
});
```

By attaching the click event handler instead to the parent div, whenever the parent sees that the event occurred in a child div with the id of `hide`, it will run the function on that child div.

(2) You shouldn't be using IDs here. If at some point you have more than one button that needs this functionality on you're page, you'll be in trouble, since an ID should only be used once per page. A class would work much better in this scenario. Then you can do something like:

```
$(".hiddendiv").on('click','.show', function () {
    $(".hiddendiv").animate({
        top: "-=250"
    }, "slow");
    $(".show").addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});
```

(3) Finally, it works! But, if we add another hiddendiv to the page, we find that when we click one, it updates all of them. We can fix that by using `this`. When the function is triggered, the `this` keyword will refer to the element that you clicked (either with the `show` or `hide` class. We can take advantage of that and do the following:

```
$(".hiddendiv").on('click','.show', function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({
        top: "-=250"
    }, "slow");
    $(this).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});

$(".hiddendiv").on('click','.hide', function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({
        top: "+=250"
    }, "slow");
    $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
});
```